# Speech recognition as a service continuously

Tags: android

How to run speech recognition in service continuously in offline, I have tried CMU but its not clearing hypothesis and reacted to every word which I spoken instead of specific command.  Thanks those who help me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it may work :

```
private final Listener listener = new Listener();

final Handler handler = new Handler();
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if(!listener.isListening()){
                                listener.listenVoice();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 500);
```

You have to create an AsynchronousTask that you will repeat every X seconds. In my case, I did every 500ms. You have to check if the listener is listening everytime because you don't want an uncomplete sentence with missing words.

I know that this solution should strange, but there isn't a proper way to do it without some Google private function.